# How do I implement a filter for my custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've been trying to add a filter to my listview which shows an array of Train Stations along with their corresponding GPS coords, filtering specifically on the name. The application however seems to crash whenever I enter more than a couple of letters since the index supposedly gets out of bounds. The reason for this, I think, is because the original unfiltered dataset gets modified whenever a filtering is published.

How do I filter properly?

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            Log.d("FILTER", "**** PUBLISHING RESULTS for: " + constraint);
            data = (List<Station>) results.values;
            StationAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.d("FILTER", "**** PERFORM FILTERING for: " + constraint);
            List<Station> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredResults;

            return results;
        }

        List<Station> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) 
        {
            List<Station> filteredResult = new ArrayList<Station>();

            if(constraint != null)
            {
                for(Station s : data)
                {
                    if(s.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))
                        filteredResult.add(s);
                }
            }

            return filteredResult;
        }
    };
}
```

The StationAdapter implements an ArrayAdapter in case this is relevant.

Stacktrace :

```
    11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at com.liteapps.handin_3.StationAdapter.getView(StationAdapter.java:50)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2257)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2435)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-29 09:17:52.025: E/AndroidRuntime(21615):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post one of those stacktraces?

Comment: See my edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Crash in getView(), so you should also post code of your adapter class.

Comment: `StationAdapter.java:line 50` check this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the getCount() method in the ArrayAdapter class.

```
     @Override
     public int getCount() {
            return YOURLIST.size();
     }
```